# .babelrc being hidden in in MacOS Mojave update causing build fail

Tags: reactjs, macos, webpack, babeljs, macos-mojave

My React projects were working fine before I updated to the new Mojave OS. After the update, none of my projects were building successfully. Turns out, all files starting with '.' get automatically hidden.

So .babelrc was nowhere to be seen and Webpack build failed.

So as a workaround, I ran the script which I found online to unhide all files:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool false
```

This works and shows the files but was wondering if anyone knows another way which would just make .babelrc unhidden instead of unhiding all files and cluttering my folders.

Also, is there a way to use a different file name (than .babelrc) which would serve the same purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: Most developers use a terminal to interact with files, and these files are not hidden in that view. It seems like adjustments to your workflow might be a better approach for you?

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround to avoid hidden files is to use `babel.config.js` instead of `.babelrc`. This file simply exports a function that returns exactly what you would have in `.babelrc`. Put the following code inside the file and modify it for your presets and plugins:

```
module.exports = function () {
  const presets = [ ... ];
  const plugins = [ ... ];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
}
```

See Babel's [official documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#babelconfigjs) on this.